# Как увеличивать массив в языке Си?

Tags: c, массивы, char

Добрый день.

Уже сломал голову как можно по ходу программы расширить массив типу **char**, так что буду рад любым советам.

Цель такая: 
(пишу компилятор) на вход в программу идёт последовательность слов. Я - не знаю сколько слов и сколько символов в них. Проблема в том, что мне нужно постепенно увеличивать массив, считывая по одному символу и сохраняя его в мой массив. Я пробовал сделать так:

```
char *symbolsArray;
int memoryCounter=1;
symbolsArray = (char *) malloc(memoryCounter)
memoryCounter=0;
//дальше идёт код...
symbolsArray[memoryCounter] = chto_to_char[i];

//Расширяю массив на один символ char
memoryCounter++;
symbolsArray = (char *) realloc(symbolsArray,memoryCounter+1);
symbolsArray[memoryCounter-1] = cto_to_char[i];
```

Comment: И? В чем проблема-то?

Comment: @AnT Как по мне - главная проблема, что на каждый чих... в смысле, `char`, вызывать `realloc()` - это уже перебор...

Comment: добавляйте память кусками по 256, когда не хватает, добавляйте еще.

Comment: Чаще всего размер увеличивают в два раза.

Comment: Для начала я бы посоветовал почитать книжки. Например, "Языки программирования, разработка и реализация". Потом чуть подумать и понять, что начальное выделение памяти в 1 байт (ну, может вы и понимаете, что malloc на самом деле выделит 16 (или около того)) это плохо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я бы делал, как `vector` в С++:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct dynArray_
{
    char * a;
    int  size;
    int count;
} dynArray;

void initDynArray(dynArray*x)
{
    x->a = malloc(x->size = 4);
    x->count = 0;
}

void killDynArray(dynArray*x)
{
    if (x->a) free(x->a);
    x->count = x->size = 0;
    x->a = NULL;
}

int addDynArray(dynArray*x, char c)
{
    if (x->a)
    {
        if (x->count == x->size)
        {
            char * ptr = realloc(x->a,x->size*2);
            if (ptr == NULL) return 0;
            x->a = ptr;
            x->size *= 2;
        }
        x->a[x->count++] = c;
        return 1;
    }
    else return 0;
}


int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    dynArray a;
    initDynArray(&a);
    for(char c = 'A'; c <= 'z'; ++c)
        if (!addDynArray(&a,c)) abort();
    addDynArray(&a,0);

    puts(a.a);

    killDynArray(&a);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

А еще можно использовать файлы, отображаемые на память (или вообще, механизмы виртуальной памяти в явном виде). Там файл будет представляться как массив. Размер.. Ну, можно выделить гигабайт или сколько не жалко. При этом, оно не будет есть реальную оперативную память (будет, но не в тех объемах. Обычно работа идет постранично). Одна беда - это очень непереносимый метод.

PS: или если не страшно - можно использовать C99 и его VLA-массивы (это почти обычные статические массивы на стеке, которые вполне законно могут менять свою длину-достаточно просто обратиться к несуществующему индексу, если правильно помню).

Comment: ** которые вполне законно могут менять свою длину-достаточно просто обратиться к несуществующему индексу, если правильно помню).**  ого,  я чего то не знаю? Обычно, обращение за пределы массива гарантировано приводит к проблемам. Или Вы путаете с javascript/php?

Comment: KoVadim, я же написал, читайте про VLA (массивы переменной длины) в стандарте C99. Да, на C99 в MS давно забили, а вот в gcc это точно реализовано. Оно, вроде, даже есть как расширение в g++. https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Length.html

Comment: я знаю, что такое VLA, но они так не могут. Вы можете просто объявить массив произвольной длины, но менять его находу, да и ещё таким наивным способом - нельзя.

Comment: @KoVadim, да, наверное, с ними я погорячился. Очень давно в последний раз читал про них и пробовал использовать...

Answer (score -1):

```
symbolsArray[memoryCounter-1] = cto_to_char[i];
```

Тут точно нужно memoryCounter-1? Разве не нужно просто memoryCounter? И ещё я предполагаю, что к i нужно добавить 1.

Comment: На самом деле, почему ты не используешь коллекции?

Comment: Да, не нужно изобретать велосипед, используйте std::vector

Comment: @user263096 В С уже ввели коллекции?

Comment: @HasmikGaryaka Начиная с какого стандарта в языке C появился `std::vector`? :)

Comment: А пусть на С++ пишет